# sending a message in a loop only once discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

as the title suggests i'm trying to send a message (only once) inside a while loop. This is the code so far:

```
while hour >= 11 and hour < 12:
   msg = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout=1, author=message.author)
   if msg:
      pass
   hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
   minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
   if hour == 11 and minute == 22:
      await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<@258621320898543616> you have 5 min of break left. Finish up whatever your doing quickly tatsu san!")
```

the code now send the message multiple times when its 11:22. I tried putting the if statement outside the loop, but it didn't send a message at all. I also tried putting `asyncio.sleep(60)` in the if statement but that didn't work either. Not sure how to get around this. Help please?

Comment: Have you tried using time.sleep() instead of asyncio.sleep()? But that will stop the entire while loop's execution for the sleep duration.

Comment: I did it just then. Thought it worked for a second but then it just stops the whole program from running. In other words, it shuts the bot down after the specified time i entered in the time.sleep() is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after researching a bit I found out a way to do this. I created a variable called "seconds" which stored (obviously) seconds. This is my new code:

```
while hour >= 11 and hour < 12:
   msg = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout=1, author=message.author)
   if msg:
      pass
   hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
   minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
   seconds = int(time.strftime("%S"))
   if hour == 11 and minute == 22 and seconds == 0:
      await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<@258621320898543616> you have 5 min of break left. Finish up whatever your doing quickly tatsu san!")
```

this did the trick. The statement only gets sent once as well